# What is the GLOBAL variable in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, global-variables

This code:
https://github.com/bjornharrtell/jsts/blob/master/index.js

refers to a variable named "GLOBAL".

When I run this in a browser, I get an error message:

"ReferenceError: GLOBAL is not defined"

Where does this GLOBAL come from, and why is it not defined?

Comment: That's a nodeJS module. You might be able to get it to work if you use Browserify, but that won't work in the browser as it stands.

Comment: Your variable is in another castle. Search through the other files

Comment: @Andy I actually used Browserify and it still didn't work... Apparently browserify didn't change these statements. They are in the bundle just the same as they are in the Node.js code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Node.js, `GLOBAL` is an [alias to the global object](https://github.com/vojtajina/node-di) (more commonly referred to as `global`).
In browsers, it doesn't exist.

Browserify recognizes the `global` alias, and will inject a reference to `window`, but does not recognize `GLOBAL`.

It was changed to `global` [four years ago](https://github.com/joyent/node/blob/master/ChangeLog#L4646-L4647)

Comment: See also https://github.com/joyent/node/blob/master/ChangeLog#L4646-L4647 and https://github.com/joyent/node/blob/master/src/node.js#L168

Answer (score 1):

Global variable came from the implementation of javascript in nodeJS

You can see it as Windows object for implementation of javascript in a web browser

Answer (score 0):

The code you are looking at is designed to run in a Node.JS environment.

The [`GLOBAL` variable is documented](http://nodejs.org/api/globals.html#globals_global) in the node manual.

It is a feature provided by the Node environment and not a core part of JavaScript.

Comment: That is not documented; Javascript is case-sensitive.