# Packaging node-webkit App Game Closure

Tags: javascript, node.js, node-webkit, gameclosure

I'm trying to package a Game Closure webapp I developed with node-webkit, but when I try to open it with the nw.exe it gives me this error:

```
Uncaught node.js Error 

ReferenceError: GLOBAL is not defined
    at new ENV_node (file:///C:/Users/FRANCE~1.FRA/AppData/Local/Temp/nw8148_5336/index.html:592:18)
    at Function.jsio.setEnv (file:///C:/Users/FRANCE~1.FRA/AppData/Local/Temp/nw8148_5336/index.html:560:11)
    at init (file:///C:/Users/FRANCE~1.FRA/AppData/Local/Temp/nw8148_5336/index.html:571:9)
    at eval (file:///C:/Users/FRANCE~1.FRA/AppData/Local/Temp/nw8148_5336/index.html:1170:10)
    at eval (file:///C:/Users/FRANCE~1.FRA/AppData/Local/Temp/nw8148_5336/index.html:1176:3)
```

I think the problem might be related to some import that doesn't work (probably jsio?).
Can someone suggest me what's going on?
Obviously the app works perfectly if I open it in a browser(tested on Chrome and Firefox).

Comment: Can you add the relevant code from index.html?  I see from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22355887/what-is-the-global-variable-in-javascript that GLOBAL is deprecated in favor of global, could it be you're using that?